# Visual studio code can't CD to filename with spaces in it

Tags: terminal, python, visual-studio

[image]

The way I have python setup on my visualstudio code is probably not the correct way of doing it. But my code runs fine on here with the exception of handling outside files to read / write

On the terminal I am trying to `cd` to the folderpath where I am trying to reada  .txt file with python

But I get an error

how do you CD to a file that has spaces in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh nevermind I figured it out its `cd "Exercise Files"`